# Neo4j RestIndex query doesn't work the 2nd instance?

Tags: java, neo4j

```
RestIndexManager rim=api.index()
RestIndex<Node> ri=rim.forNodes("students");
System.out.println(ri.query("student_ID:student13").getSingle());
System.out.println(ri.query("student_ID:student13").getSingle());
```

**http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1004**

**null**

When I query the db on Index again, it returns **NULL**. Why is it so?

Comment: Can you share any errors in the database server logs in data/logs and data/graph.db/messages.log ?